# glusterfs: "merge" two 1 x (2+1) = 3 arbiter volumes

Tags: glusterfs

The system I inherited has 2 arbiter volumes:

1 x (2+1) = 3

Every evening the "live" volume rsync to the "standby" volume.

I would rather make the "standby" volume part of the "live" volume for an arbiter config of:

2 x (2+1) = 6

I'm struggling to find any documentation on how I can keep the "live" volume intact and add the "standby" volume to it as indicated. (The "standby" volume can be discarded/formatted/recreated)

Any push in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add a node to glusterfs?

You can add 1 node and specify type of volume as replica, glusterfs will work automatically.

Comment: Thanks. It does not allow me to add a normal brick. It says wrong brick type.
Upon further research, arbiter volumes can only accept "replica 3 arbiter 1" additions.
I.e. sets of 3 bricks must be added, 2 normal bricks, 1 arbiter brick.